# How to solve expo build faild

Tags: react-native, expo

When I try to create the apk file ( expo build:android -c) for the second time
The following error was shown Please help

Waiting for build to complete.
You can press Ctrl+C to exit. It won't cancel the build, you'll be able to monitor it at the printed URL.
× Build failed.
Standalone build failed!

Answer (score 0):

Just run `expo build:android` normally, without `-c` tag

Comment: Thanks , i could be able to fixed this , by removing  "enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds": true,'   on app.json , I put this '"enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds": true,' to reduce app size on android : {'"enableDangerousExperimentalLeanBuilds": true,' }